# Align a plot and a text at top using Row or Grid

Tags: alignment

I'm a little embarrassed asking such a simple question, but it's a problem I'm having since a long time. I want to e.g. have a plot beside some text. Now, I want that the top line of the plot and the top line of the text are at the same hight. I can't get this to work. When I use Alignment -> Top the text is always aligned at the middle and I don't know why. This sounds all very simple, so any help is appreciated.
E.g.

```
Row[{ListPlot[{1, 2, 1, 3}, Joined -> True, Frame -> True,ImageSize -> 400], "    ", Framed@Grid[{{"test"}, {"test2"}}]}, Alignment -> Top]
```

The result is>

[image]

So top line of plot and of text not at the same height.

Comment: Use `Grid[{{...}},Alignment->{Center,Top}]`. p.s. `Spacer` is neater than `"     "`.

Comment: I tried this, but then the text is below the plot. I want it beside the plot, but so that the lines at the top of the plot and that of the text are aligned. So, the text needs to go higher. – Thanks for the 'Spacer' tip, though.

Comment: I believe you are talking about `Grid[{{...},{...}}]`. It's not what I meant, the answer of PatoCorillo is.

Comment: Yes, I have it now. Thanks. I didn't realise this doesn't work with Row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Grid[{{ListPlot[{1, 2, 1, 3}, Joined -> True, Frame -> True, 
    ImageSize -> 400], Framed@Grid[{{"test"}, {"test2"}}]}}, 
 Alignment -> Top]
```

Comment: OK, interesting, now I got it. Curious this doesn't work with Row! Thanks.